# Different Data tyoes for datum

Tags: datum, data

I have two main actions that user can do. They both require sending utxos to a script address. The datum I want produced by these two actions are different. I want one of the datum like this

```
data VotingDatum = VotingDatum
  { projectPubKey :: PaymentPubKeyHash
  , amount :: Integer
  , fund :: Integer
  , paymentPubKey :: PaymentPubKeyHash
  }deriving (Show)
```

and the other one like this.

```
data StartDatum = StartDatum
 { startFund :: Integer
 , fundPrize :: Integer
 }deriving (Show)
```

I was thinking of putting these two in a single data type like this

```
data ContractDatum = ContractDatum
 { voteDatum :: Maybe VotingDatum
 , startDatum :: Maybe StartDatum
 }
```

How would i set the value of these fields if i did it like this. Can i do it like this ?
I am currently setting the value of the types like this

```
start sp = do 
    let dat = StartDatum
                { startFund = spFund sp 
                , fundPrize = spAmount sp
                }
```

How can i have two different data types for the datum. How can i set the value of it , and how would i access the value of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two like this

```
data DatumAction = VotingDatum | StartDatum
```

Then you can specify in you validator which case is used like this

```
mkValidator :: DatumAction -> redeemer -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator datumAction redeemer context = case datumAction of
    VotingDatum -> do something with type bool
    StartDatum  -> do something with type bool
```

Hope this helps, also see [(1)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type) and [(2)](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html).

Comment: Yea , this is what i am looking for but I think i am missing something.It giving errors saying it couldn't match type StartDatum with type DatumAction and it couldnt match type VotingDatum with type Datum Action